# responsive WP site not working in ie8

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, media-queries, responsive-design

i have a problem with ie8 not displaying the site correctly it seems to be using the mobile styles and not the browser ones.

i have respond.js polyfill loading but looks likes it not working...

here is the site online
http://www.mediacake.net/cake123/ecomore/

the original template works but iv made extensive changes to the layout mainly homepage

http://demo2.woothemes.com/?name=shelflife

if anyone can help i would be grateful

Comment: Are you using an html shiv to force IE to recognise your html5 markup as divs?  http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: i wasnt using this before but iv just added to the header and nothing changed....

Answer (score 0):

Your page has the following...

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="http://www.mediacake.net/cake123/ecomore/wp-content/themes/shelflife/includes/js/respond-IE.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

If you want it to work in IE8, shouldn't it look more like...

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://www.mediacake.net/cake123/ecomore/wp-content/themes/shelflife/includes/js/respond-IE.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```